# How can I install texlive-humanities to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, latex

I tried to install `texlive-humanities`to Ubuntu 19.04 but it looks like there is problems with broken packages. How can I solve this issue?

```
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install texlive-humanities
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-humanities : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install texlive-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-base is already the newest version (2018.20190227-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop$ apt policy texlive-{base,humanities}
texlive-base:
  Installed: 2018.20190227-1
  Candidate: 2018.20190227-1
  Version table:
 *** 2018.20190227-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2017.20180305-1 500
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
texlive-humanities:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2017.20180305-2
  Version table:
     2017.20180305-2 500
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: Do you remember how you installed `texlive-base`?

Comment: You say "Ubuntu 19.04" but appear to have 18.04 (bionic) repositories